# android searchView in actionbar filter issue

Tags: android, searchview

i have searchview in the action bar it is not working i try to do this like as

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    // Inflate menu to add items to action bar if it is present.
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    android.support.v7.widget.SearchView searchView =
            (android.support.v7.widget.SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
    return true;
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){


        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }

        });

}
```

but it give me error that android.support.v7.widget.SearchViewOnQueryTextListener in searchview can not be apply

Comment: move `return true;` at last

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    // Inflate menu to add items to action bar if it is present.
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    android.support.v7.widget.SearchView searchView =
            (android.support.v7.widget.SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener(){


        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return false;
        }
        });
return true;
}
```

1. Return should be at the end,
2. last three braces where not in correct order.